# Show that the Communicating classes C1 and C2 can be either C1 = C2 or C1 intersection C2 = empty

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The question is if we are given 2 communicating classes: C1 and C2, the we have to prove that C1 = C2 or C1 intersection C2 = empty.

I know that a communicating state can be recurrent or transient, but I am not sure how to deal with classes. Can someone show me the prove for this one.

Comment: How do you define a "communicating class"?  iirc, in my classes, we defined communication, showed it was an equivalence relation, and then defined communicating classes as the equivalence classes.  In that case, though, your question is redundant (unless you just want to prove for the $n$th time that equivalence classes form a partition)

Comment: C is said to be a communicating class if for i,j belongs to C, i <-> j and i belongs to C and i<-> j then j belongs to C